# Exercise about inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This exercise is from *Apostol's Calculus*:

> $|1 + 3x| \le 1$ implies $x \ge -{\frac 23}$

I answered **false**, but the right answer is **true**. My understanding is — of course all $x$ are bigger than $-{\frac 23}$, but if $x$ is $1000$ the first inequality is obviously wrong.

Comment: Your confusion is a logical one. Do you understand what *implies* means?

Comment: Your thinking is right, but you have your logic reversed. You answered correctly if you misinterpreted the statement as: $x\ge -2/3 ~\text{ implies } |1+3x| \le 1$. Based on your explanation, this is your misinterpretation.

Comment: @GitGud: "A *implies* B" means if A is true than B must be true.

Comment: For $x=1000$, is $A$ true?

Comment: @GitGud, no, but you're moving reverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's the arithmetic that confuses you.
Hopefully we agree that depending on what $x$ is, we can be in one of three situtations:

- $|1 + 3x| \le 1$ is false and $x \ge -{\frac 23}$ is also false (for example when $x=-3$).
- $|1 + 3x| \le 1$ is true and $x \ge -{\frac 23}$ is also true (for example when $x=-\frac13$).
- $|1 + 3x| \le 1$ is false but $x \ge -{\frac 23}$ is true (for example when $x=3$).

In *each of these cases* it holds that $|1 + 3x| \le 1$ implies $x \ge -{\frac 23}$, because the **only way** for "$P$ implies $Q$" *not* to hold is if $P$ is true and $Q$ is false. And that is never the case with these formulas.

Note that strictly speaking a thing like "$|1 + 3x| \le 1$ implies $x \ge -{\frac 23}$" in its entirety is a claim that depends on the value of $x$. For example, "$x\ge0$ implies $x=10$" is *true* whenever $x$ happens to be $10$ or negative, but is false when $x$ is $0$ or positive and different from $10$.

When the exercise asks about "$|1 + 3x| \le 1$ implies $x \ge -{\frac 23}$" what it really means is

> For every possible $x$ it holds that $|1 + 3x| \le 1$ implies $x \ge -{\frac 23}$

which happens to be true here because there is no $x$ that makes the implication false. The logical notion of "$P$ implies $Q$" is designed to be useful in a situation where $P$ and $Q$ depend on some parameters, and what we're really interested in is being able to say "for every choice of $x$, $y$, $z$, it will be that $P(x,y,z)$ implies $Q(x,y,z)$". That's just the mathematical way of saying "whenever you find some $x$, $y$, $z$ that make $P(x,y,z)$ true, those $x,y,z$ will also make $Q(x,y,z)$". By design that tells you nothing about what happens to $Q$ in choices where $P$ is false.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{array}{l}
|1+3x|\le 1 &\iff -1 \le 1 +3x \le 1\\
&\iff -2\le 3x \le 0\\
&\iff -\frac{2}{3}\le x \le 0\\
&\iff -\frac{2}{3}\le x \text{ and } x \le 0\\
&\implies -\frac{2}{3}\le x
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$|1+3x|\leqslant 1\iff -1\leqslant 1+3x\leqslant 1$$
Solving for $x$:
$$-2\leqslant 3x\leqslant 0\iff \dfrac{-2}3\leqslant x\leqslant0\implies\dfrac{-2}3\leqslant x
$$
Your confusion regarding *Apostol's* statement is rather a logical one. Read in those two links what *implies* mean: [$1$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Implies.html), [$2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols).

Answer (score 0):

For real $b\ge0, y$  $$|y|\le b\iff -b\le y\le b$$

$$\implies|1+3x|\le1\iff -1\le 1+3x\le1$$